# C++ problems with string

Tags: c++, c, string, include

I am doing some arduino development using cpp and h files and I am having some troubles using string with them. Currently I have

```
#include <string>
```

at the top of both the cpp and the h file. When I do that it gives me the error:

```
string: no such file or directory
```

If I go into the h file and change it to

```
#include <string.h>
```

then it gives me the error:

```
std::string has not been declared
```

Anytime I use the string I use: std::string to declare it. I am not using namespace std and these files were working together fine before I started to try to use string. I am new to C/C++ so I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have a C++ platform?

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. This sounds like compiling the source code as C, with a C compiler. `<string.h>` is a C header, and does not declare `std::string`.

Comment: It might be C I could be wrong. If I remove the "std::" then it say "string has not been declared." How would I use string?

Comment: Arduino is neither C nor C++, it's a custom language that just looks kind of like C. It does not include support for any of the C++ standard library.

Comment: @MrEricSir then how would I use string, if it's even possible?

Comment: @DerekSchuster You certainly can't use std::string, but Arduino has its own String object: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, there is a way to use `std::string` with the Arduino.

TL;DR:
[link to the arduino STLv1.1.2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zty39b0gqeh1waf/avr-stl-1.1.2.zip?dl=0)

#### NOTE

Please note that currently the harrdwareserialstream class provided by this STL should be considered broken (as per my testing, with version 1.6.5 of the IDE, and possibly anything after 1.0.6). therefore, you can't use

```
hardwareserialstream << "Hi there person number " << (int)i
```

and so on. it seems to no longer work due to taking a reference to the serial port it would interact with rather than a pointer - in short, continue using

```
Serial.print("Hi there person number");
Serial.print((int)i);
```

Lastly the serial classes don't know what a `std::string` is, so if using them, give it `std::string.c_str()` instead

## Background

As McEricSir says in the comments, the arduino does provide its own string class, though i have found it to have problems related to memory leakage, which eventually ate all of the memory i had and the program stopped running - though this was in the arduino IDE v 1.0.5, it may have been fixed since then.

I had the same problem, and found someone who had created a version of the [STL for the arduino](http://andybrown.me.uk/2011/01/15/the-standard-template-library-stl-for-avr-with-c-streams/) (props to Andy Brown for this) which is a cutdown version of the SGI STL. it provides std::string, std::vector and a large amount of the STL to the arduino.

there are some things to be aware when using it though; if you have a board with very little memory, you will fill it quite quickly using the smart containers and other advanced features.

## Using the Library

To use the library, you'll need to read the article, though I'll summarise the main points for you here:

### Installation

simply extract the library to (assuming you are using the standard Arduino IDE) `hardware\tools\avr\avr\include` folder and you are good to go.

## Using It

To actually use the new libraries, you need to include 2 additional things as well as the library you wanted.

firstly, you need to include the header `iterator` **BEFORE** any libraries that come from this STL - and in every file you reference the STL in.

Secondly, you also need to include the file `pnew.cpp` to provide an implementation of the `new` operator for the STL to work with.

Lastly, include any header files as you would normally.

to make use of the types gained from them, don't forget the the `std::` namespace notation for them. (`std::string` and so on)

## Bugs with it

Since Andy posted the library, there have been two bugs (that i'm aware of).

The first one Andy himself rectifies and explain in the blog post:

> The compiler will spit out a typically cryptic succession of template errors, with the key error being this one:
>
> dependent-name `std::basic_string::size_type` is parsed as a non-type,
>   but instantiation yields a type c:/program files (x86)/arduino-1.0/
>   hardware/tools/avr/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/string:1106: note: 
>   say `typename std::basic_string::size_type` if a type is meant
>
> Basically the STL was written a long time ago when C++ compilers were a little more forgiving around dependent types inherited from templates. These days they are rightly more strict and you are forced to explicitly say that you mean a type using the typename keyword.

Additionally, he provides the updated version for you to grab.

Lastly, there are reports in the comments about a bug in the newer versions of the IDE pertaining to the vector class where the compiler complains about the use of `_M_deallocate` without a prepending `this->`, which you can fix if you search for them inside the vector class

### For your convenience

As i use this quite frequently, i've packaged up the current version, which [can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zty39b0gqeh1waf/avr-stl-1.1.2.zip?dl=0) (this includes both the fixes i have commented on)

#### Lastly

When using this, make sure to keep an eye on your free memory, and to that end i recommend the excellent class [MemoryFree Library found here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvailableMemory)

on a side note if you `#include<string>` inside the header you won't need to include it in the relevant .cpp file